# can I drop error checking the memory allocation to a pointer if alocated memory is very small (like 64 bytes)?

Tags: c, malloc

I'm writing a simple utility in C and I'm writing codes to print error messages in STDERR.

I have a struct, defined as:

```
struct arguments
{
    FILE *source;
    int modifier_value;
    int filesize;
};
```

---

I have declared a pointer to the above struct, and allocated memory to it:

```
struct arguments *arg = NULL;
arg = malloc(sizeof(struct arguments));
if(arg == NULL)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "error: malloc - %s\n", strerror(errno));  //I know i could use perror as well, but I like the convention of using fprintf() for both stdout, stderr, and other file streams, just for symmetry
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

As you can see, I have only allocated memory sufficient to store one object of type `struct arguments` and I still error checking for it.

The problem is I have many pointers like that which points to space of one object, and error checking all of them just increases number of codes and affects readability of code.

Is it a "good practice" / "is it ok" if I **ignore** error checking just for the reason that **I'm not allocating memory too much memory** (I heard something about paging and I think system combines many pages if I request for too much memory and chances of error in that case would be high, but not for memory request of something like 64 bytes).

Comment: Create a macro/wrapper function for the repeated code.

Comment: Yes it's a good idea. You don't know what's happening elsewhere on your computer, what other processes might have used the (virtual) memory.

Comment: ..and pass enough information to identify the source.

Comment: Also, never lay off the good habits. If you start making small easy shortcuts, then it's easier to to it elsewhere where it might really matter.

Comment: Yes, it is only one step from writing code that falls over when the user sneezes. You need *robust* code.

Comment: @WeatherVane `and pass enough information to identify the source` - I'm not a professional programmer, so I dont know standard practices. If I want to identity the source, do I have to stick to one convention (like always name the function which generated error) or can I be flexible in naming (like name the thing which triggers my mind about the exact source, may not be the name of source function or variable). I want to know how professionals do this naming.

Comment: You can pass an argument to identify the caller. Perhaps as unique integer (although that is hard to maintain), or the `__func__` name which [resolves to a string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/func?view=msvc-170). For example declare/define `void *my_malloc(size_t size, const char *func);` and then call as `arg = my_malloc(sizeof(struct arguments), __func__);`

Comment: ... you can pass anything to your wrapper which will direct you to the source of the error – that's your decision. In the previous comment, you might have more than one `malloc` in the same function.

Comment: Adding the name of the function or the name of the source file containing the call that failed is *not* useful.  Neither is a stack trace.  If your process is consuming excessive memory, you want to determine what component is doing it with other instrumentation.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Fair point that other instrumentation commonly exists - yet not always or not after deployment.  Hence by wrapping that info (function name, ...) in a macro, code can selectively use or not use such overhead data with a simple macro change rather than a large code base change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it a "good practice" / "is it ok" if I **ignore** error checking just for the reason that **I'm not allocating memory too much memory**

It is **poor** practice to fail to error-check function calls that report on errors, except where you don't care whether the call succeeded.  And you *always* care whether `malloc()` succeeds, or else you shouldn't be calling it in the first place.  You don't know whether you are allocating too much memory unless you check whether your `malloc()` calls succeed.

> The problem is I have many pointers like that which points to space of one object, and error checking all of them just increases number of codes and affects readability of code.

In the first place, use dynamic allocation only where you actually need it.  Some people seem to have the idea that they need dynamic allocation wherever they want a pointer to an object.  This absolutely is not the case.  You need pointers if you are performing dynamic allocation, but you don't necessarily need dynamic allocation where you use pointers.  Very often, static or automatic allocation can be combined with the address-of operator (unary `&`) instead.  For example:

```
{
    struct arguments arg = {0};
    init_arguments(&arg);
    do_something(&arg);
    // all done with arg
}
```

You need dynamic allocation only when (i) you do not know at compile time how much memory you will need, or (ii) you need an object whose lifetime extends past the termination of the innermost block enclosing its creation.

When you really do need dynamic allocation, you can reduce the amount of boilerplate code by using a macro or a wrapper function.  Similar applies to performing other success checks.  For example, use a function such as this instead of using `malloc()` directly:

```
void *checked_malloc(size_t size) {
    void *result = malloc(size);

    if (result == NULL && size != 0) {
        fputs("error: malloc failed -- aborting...\n", stderr);
        abort();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Even with C17, `checked_malloc(0)` may still result in an `abort()`.  IMO, better to simply return `NULL` or change to `if (!result && size > 0) {` to handle this pesky corner case.

Comment: Good point, @chux-ReinstateMonica.  I have updated the example code accordingly.

Comment: Cinverse, Notice what has been just demonstrated here with John and me.   A corner case improvement that only needed changes to one small function.  Consider a large program that had many `malloc()` all over the place that had to deal with this and the large change needed.  So nice to have the `malloc()` in one place.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Yeah, understood, thanks. Also, I think it would be good if value of `size` is mentioned in error message, as it would be another step ahead to identify exactly which call caused error.  if `size` value is some garbage value, then we can Identify source by checking which code had the potential to make `size` have such value.

Comment: If that seems good to you, @Cinverse, then by all means go ahead.  The code presented in this answer is meant to be demonstrative, not definitive.  I applied the correction chux suggested as a matter of correctness for a corner case, but I consider the details of the error message to be a matter of fitting such a function to your particular purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Create allocation wrapper functions to make always checking allocation success easy.

To expand on [@Weather Vane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74437149/problem-with-error-checking-for-every-malloc-call/74437393?noredirect=1#comment131404930_74437149) idea of passing an argument to identify the caller, yet do it in a macro wrapper.

my_malloc.h

```
#ifndef MY_MALLOC
#define MY_MALLOC(size) my_malloc((size), __FUNC__, __LINE__)
#include <stdlib.h>

// Return a valid allocation or don't return.
void *my_malloc(size_t size, const char *func, unsigned line);

#endif
```

my_malloc.c

```
#include "my_maloc.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void *my_malloc(size_t size, const char *func, unsigned line) {
  if (size == 0) {
    return NULL;
  }
  void *ptr = malloc(size);
  if (ptr == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to allocate %zu bytes at \"%s()\", line %u\n",
        size, func, line);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  return ptr;
}
```

user_code.c

```
#include "my_malloc.h"

...
  // No need to explicitly pass the function name, line number
  arg = MY_MALLOC(sizeof *arg * n);
  // Error checking not needed.

  ...
  free(arg);
```

---

I'd even consider a matching `MY_FREE` where freeing passes in the pointer and the expected size.  Then those 2 routines could keep allocation statistics, free size validation, ...

Answer (score -1):

If you have many objects, you cam allocate memory for all immediately:

```
void *pvc;
pvc = malloc(how_many_for_all);
```

and then consecutively declare pointers to objects like this:

```
Obj1 *p1;
Obj2 *p2;
Obj3 *p3;
p1 = (Obj1)pvc;
p2 = (Obj2)(pvc + sizeof(Obj1));
p3 = (Obj3)(pvc + sizeof(Obj1) + sizeof(Obj2));
```

This is pseudocode sooner. Compiler will be make warnings, but this works.

Comment: 1) `(Obj2)(pvc + sizeof(Obj1))` should be `(Obj2*)((char *)pvc + sizeof(Obj1))` else the addition is wrong.   2) This works OK if the objects are the same size.  If different, then alignment issues come into play.

Comment: My mistake, p1 = (Obj1 *)pvc;